# oracle blob text search

Tags: oracle, search, blob

Is it possible to search through blob text using sql statement?
I can do select * from $table where f1 like '%foo%' if the f1 is varchar, how about f1 is a blob? Any counter part for this?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This is quite possible and easy to do.

Simply use dbms_lob.instr in conjunction with utl_raw.cast_to_raw

So in your case, if t1 is a BLOB the select would look like:

```
select *
  from table1
 where dbms_lob.instr (t1, -- the blob
                   utl_raw.cast_to_raw ('foo'), -- the search string cast to raw
                   1, -- where to start. i.e. offset
                   1 -- Which occurrance i.e. 1=first
                    ) > 0 -- location of occurrence. Here I don't care.  Just find any
;
```

Comment: ++ When the database isn't yours, to say the schema is wrong isn't helpful all.  Thank you so much for resurrecting and answering the question!

Comment: And this indeed should be the accepted answer - the question was clearly about BLOB and not about CLOB!

Comment: This is the correct answer. The one marked as the correct answer is a good answer for a different question: "Which data type should I use when storing a large amount of text?".

Comment: I had to search for a Unicode character, so I adapted this solution as follows: select * from table1 where dbms_lob.instr (f1, utl_raw.cast_to_raw (**unistr('\D83D')**), 1, 1) > 0;

Answer (score 5):

If it is a Word or PDF document, look into [Oracle Text](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/toc.htm).

Answer (score 3):

If you are storing plain text it should be a CLOB, not a BLOB, and then you can still query using LIKE.  A BLOB contains binary data that Oracle doesn't know the structure of, so it cannot search it in this way.

This works for CLOBs of **any** length (at least on Oracle 12C):

```
SQL> create table t1 (c clob);

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2     x clob;
  3  begin
  4     for i in 1..100 loop
  5        x := x || rpad('x', 32767, 'x');
  6     end loop;
  7     x := x || 'z';
  8     for i in 1..100 loop
  9        x := x || rpad('x', 32767, 'x');
 10     end loop;
 11     insert into t1 values (x);
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select dbms_Lob.getlength(c) from t1 where c like '%z%';

DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(C)
---------------------
              6553401
```

Note that there is only one 'z' in that 6,554,401 byte CLOB - right in the middle of it:

```
SQL> select instr(c, 'z') from t1;

INSTR(C,'Z')
------------
     3276701
```

Comment: @Olafur has a good helpful answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16301995/510711

Comment: This is also wrong.   It only works for CLOBS that are <32767 characters. Which is pretty small.    instr and like will break after that the you have to use dbms_lob.instr to search.

Comment: @Olafur: your criticism is false as I have updated my answer to show.

Comment: Stand corrected,  it used to be (earlier versions) that like and instr where varchar2.  11g and 12c have overloaded it with a clob version

Answer (score 0):

the below code is to display the details from blob as text using [UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_raw.htm#i1007280) then we use [substr function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) to cut the text from the start of expected data till end. however, you can use  [instr function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564), [LENGTH function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm)   , if you know the location of the data you are looking for

```
select NVL(SUBSTR(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(blob_body), 
INSTR(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(blob_body), '<ns:xml_element>') + LENGTH('<ns:xml_element>'),
INSTR(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(blob_body), '</ns:xml_element>') - (
INSTR(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(blob_body), '<ns:xml_element>') + LENGTH('<ns:xml_element>'))),
    utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(blob_body))
    ) blob_body
from dual 
where SUBSTR(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(blob_body), 
INSTR(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(blob_body), '<ns:xml_element>') + LENGTH('<ns:xml_element>'),
INSTR(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(blob_body), '</ns:xml_element>') - (
INSTR(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(blob_body), '<ns:xml_element>') + LENGTH('<ns:xml_element>'))) like '%foo%';
```

Answer (score -3):

Select * From TABLE_NAME 
and dbms_lob.instr("BLOB_VARIABLE_NAME", utl_raw.cast_to_raw('search_text'), 1, 1) > 0