# Conditions (like "like") on binary field (blob) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, search, full-text-search, blob

How can I search in (put condition on) blob field in oracle, like text fields?

I need someting like:

```
select * from table_name where blob_field like '%00ff00ff%'
```

Oracle throws some error on it.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963793/oracle-blob-text-search

Answer (score 30):

You can use dbms_lob.instr for this purpose i.e.

```
   select * from table_name 
   where dbms_lob.instr(blob_field, utl_raw.CAST_TO_RAW('00ff00ff'), 1, 1) > 0
```

Comment: The pattern for searching BLOBs has to be a RAW datatype. Oh, and I corrected the package name in the sample too ;)

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful (came across this a year after you answered!)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from NDF_MODEL_PARAM
where dbms_lob.instr(VALUE, 'NaN') > 0;
```