# Search Text in blob in hsql

Tags: java, search, blob, hsqldb

I know it's possible to search for text in blobs in oracle db. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963793/oracle-blob-text-search/16301995#16301995))

But is it possible in hsql?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use LIKE, POSITION or regular expressions. See the built-in functions for different options.