# ORACLE -LIKE condition in JSON_VALUE (BLOB FIELD) not working?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, blob, oracle12c

I have one table with a blob field called BLOBFIELD.

This:

```
SELECT A.ID
FROM   A AP 
WHERE  JSON_VALUE(
         AP.BLOBFIELD format json,
         '$.arrays.AAA.arrays.BBB.fields.Name'
       ) = 'peter'
```

works fine when I use equals. But this:

```
SELECT A.ID
FROM   A AP 
WHERE  JSON_VALUE(
         AP.BLOBFIELD format json,
         '$.arrays.AAA.arrays.BBB.fields.Name'
       ) LIKE 'peter%'
```

and:

```
SELECT A.ID
FROM   A AP 
WHERE  (JSON_VALUE(
         AP.BLOBFIELD format json,
         '$.arrays.AAA.arrays.BBB.fields.Name'
       )) LIKE '%peter%'
```

I don´t have error, but I think that it not work because   AAA and BBB are arrays
I found regex_like but this function receive such as first value a field, but I don´t have field I have a json path.

```
SELECT A.ID FROM A AP 
WHERE JSON_VALUE( AP.BLOBFIELD format json, '$.arrays.AAA[*].arrays.BBB[*].fields.Name' ERROR ON ERROR ) LIKE 'peter%'
```

are not working. How can I get it to work using `LIKE`?

Comment: By "not working", do you mean you get an error, or just no results returned?

Comment: No results returned

Comment: this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/16301995/3377472 show an example.

Comment: will be dbms_lob.instr(AP.BLOBFIELD,utl_raw.CAST_TO_RAW('hello'),1,1)>0                     But I have a json_value                                                                    JSON_VALUE(
         AP.BLOBFIELD format json,
         '$.arrays.AAA.arrays.BBB.fields.Name'
       )

Answer (score 1):

JSON_VALUE cannot be used to access a key that occurs more than once in a docment. Eg if the key or any of its parents are arrays then the content cannot be accessed via JSON_VALUE unless the JSON_PATH expression uses indices to identify a particular member of the array.

We need to use JSON_TABLE to solve this one...

```
SQL> WITH A as
  2  (  select 1 ID,
  3           '{"arrays":[{"AAA":{"arrays":[{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Max"}}},{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Mike"}}}]}},{"AA
A":{"arrays":[{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Mark"}}},{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Matt"}}}]}}]}' BLOBFIELD
  4      from DUAL
  5     union all
  6     select 2 ID,
  7           '{"arrays":[{"AAA":{"arrays":[{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Pat"}}},{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Pete"}}}]}},{"AA
A":{"arrays":[{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Paul"}}},{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Pascal"}}}]}}]}' BLOBFIELD
  8      from DUAL
  9  )
 10  SELECT distinct AP.ID
 11   FROM  A AP,
 12         JSON_TABLE(
 13           AP.BLOBFIELD,
 14           '$.arrays[*]'
 15           COLUMNS
 16           NESTED PATH
 17           '$.AAA.arrays[*]'
 18           COLUMNS (
 19             NAME VARCHAR2(32) PATH '$.BBB.fields.Name'
 20           )
 21        )
 22  where NAME LIKE '%Pete%'
 23
SQL>       /
         2
```

Just for completeness.

The reason you got no rows with JSON_VALUE is the default "NULL ON ERROR" behavior. This can be see by adding the ERROR OR ERROR clause as can be seen below

```
SQL> WITH A as
  2  (  select 1 ID,
  3           '{"arrays":[{"AAA":{"arrays":[{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Max"}}},{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Mike"}}}]}},{"AA
A":{"arrays":[{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Mark"}}},{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Matt"}}}]}}]}' BLOBFIELD
  4      from DUAL
  5     union all
  6     select 2 ID,
  7           '{"arrays":[{"AAA":{"arrays":[{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Pat"}}},{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Pete"}}}]}},{"AA
A":{"arrays":[{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Paul"}}},{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Pascal"}}}]}}]}' BLOBFIELD
  8      from DUAL
  9  )
 10  SELECT AP.ID
 11  FROM   A AP
 12  WHERE  JSON_VALUE(
 13           AP.BLOBFIELD format json,
 14           '$.arrays.AAA.arrays.BBB.fields.Name'
 15         ) LIKE 'peter%'
 16  /

no rows selected

SQL> WITH A as
  2  (  select 1 ID,
  3           '{"arrays":[{"AAA":{"arrays":[{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Max"}}},{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Mike"}}}]}},{"AA
A":{"arrays":[{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Mark"}}},{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Matt"}}}]}}]}' BLOBFIELD
  4      from DUAL
  5     union all
  6     select 2 ID,
  7           '{"arrays":[{"AAA":{"arrays":[{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Pat"}}},{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Pete"}}}]}},{"AA
A":{"arrays":[{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Paul"}}},{"BBB":{"fields":{"Name":"Pascal"}}}]}}]}' BLOBFIELD
  8      from DUAL
  9  )
 10  SELECT AP.ID
 11  FROM   A AP
 12  WHERE  JSON_VALUE(
 13           AP.BLOBFIELD format json,
 14           '$.arrays.AAA.arrays.BBB.fields.Name'
 15           ERROR ON ERROR
 16         ) LIKE 'peter%'
 17  /
FROM   A AP
       *
ERROR at line 11:
ORA-40470: JSON_VALUE evaluated to multiple values


SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran JSON_VALUE using LIKE and it worked perfectly. I tested on 12.1.0.2 RELEASE and later versions.
What happens if you use ERROR ON ERROR clause in  your JSON_VALUE?

SELECT A.ID
FROM   A AP 
WHERE  JSON_VALUE(
         AP.BLOBFIELD format json,
         '$.arrays.AAA.arrays.BBB.fields.Name' ERROR ON ERROR
       ) LIKE 'peter%'

are you seeing an error?

Comment: I don´t have error, but I think that it not work because   AAA and BBB are arrays   Example.                                                                                            SELECT A.ID FROM A AP WHERE JSON_VALUE( AP.BLOBFIELD format json, '$.arrays.AAA[*].arrays.BBB[*].fields.Name' ERROR ON ERROR ) LIKE 'peter%'